# Component diagram relationship between files

Tags: architecture, uml, diagram, component-diagram

I'm trying to make a component diagram for some missing animal search system.

1. pet911.js (scripts) is a component that is used to handle events on
   the client side. Scripts process the data that users enter on the
   system pages and send this data to the server for further
   processing.
2. pet911.html(Web interface) is a component that provides user
   interaction with the system. It contains various pages.
3. pet911-payment.js is a component that provides payment processing
   through third-party payment systems.
4. pet911-server.js is a component that runs a server application and
   processes requests from clients
5. pet911-router.js is a component that handles request routing on the
   server
6. pet911-controller.js is a component that processes application logic
   on the server
7. pet911-utils.dll - is a  component with utilities for various jobs
   such as data encryption and decryption  for exmp..
8. pet911-data-access.js is a component that provides functions for
   interacting with the database
9. pet911-db-connector.dll - is a component for connecting to the
   database
10. pet911.db - is a database

I am bad at software architecture and would like to ask if I have correctly depicted the connections between the components.I would also like to get recommendations about whether some components are redundant, or whether some more need to be added?

Also I have a little question about pet911-payment.js . I decided to put this in a separate component, since it will use payment services (that is, something third-party) Is it possible to somehow depict this on a component diagram?

I would also like to know how I can supplement my diagram? Because it looks rather crude, for example, to specify database tables, etc., to provide some additional information.I would be grateful if you would provide resources where i can get acquainted with this and see examples.

[image]

(my diagram is similar to the Modeling source code technique, i guess..but I don't see any additional information on the diagram, except for various files.(this is a diagram from the internet as an example) )

[image]

Comment: The connectios are ok, though «parent» is not a standard and needs a profile. I would extend the components to show interfaces.

Comment: @qwerty_so are there any examples?(it is better to provide links)because I do not know how to describe and draw it correctly..

Comment: You mean reagarding the interfaces? I think you should browse https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html